# How to specify the endianness of utf-16 string literals in C++17 with Clang?

Tags: c++, unicode, clang, standards, c++17

UTF-16 string literals, such as `auto str = u"中国字";`, are allowed in modern C++ source code.

UTF-16 has two endiannesses: UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE. The C++ standard doesn't specify the endianness of UTF-16 string literals. So, I think it is implementation-defined.

Is there any way to specify the endianness at compile-time?

Comment: That's really one of the main reasons you should *not* use UTF-16 (or UTF-32) if you want to transfer the strings between programs or systems. Use UTF-8 instead. Internally inside your program use whatever encoding you want, but not when saving to a file or when transferring over a network.

Comment: UTF-8 has its disadvantages: It's hard to sort and search. So, in some cases, UTF-16 is preferred.

Comment: As I modified my comment to say, you can use it *internally* inside your program (as long as you're aware of that it will not represent all of Unicode and is a variable-length encoding). *Externally* outside the program, use UTF-8.

Comment: The short answer is "no". Unicode string literals use the natural endian-ness of the implementation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, My real issue is: if I have many UTF-16LE strings loaded from network, and the local natural endianness is UTF-16BE, then I must convert them dynamically, which is time-consuming, rather than just statically specify the endianness.

Comment: It's not implementation defined, its up to you the programmer to decide which to use and when. The standard won't force programmers to use one or the other when they sometimes need to use both.

Comment: The standard doesn't require that you can actually embed unicode characters in the source code

Comment: @Galik, You are right, but the implemntation should give the programmer a way to choose which endianness to use.

Comment: @xmllmx In what respect? How is the implementation going to force the issue one way or another? If you are loading a file from disk, it could be either. It is for the programmer to figure that out.

Comment: If that's the case then someone made a terrible mistake during design (in my *not* humble opinion). However then you don't really deal with constant string literals, and can use whatever endianness you need for your internal strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal prefixed with `u` is an array of `const char16_t` values:

C++17 [lex.string]/10:

> A string-literal that begins with `u` , such as `u"asdf"`, is a `char16_t` string literal. A `char16_t` string literal has type “array of n const `char16_t`”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it is initialized with the given characters.

So the literal in the quote is equivalent to, on a Unicode system:

```
const char16_t x[] = { 97, 115, 100, 102, 0 };
```

In other words, the representation of the string literal is the same as the representation of that array.

For a more complicated string, it is still an array of `const char16_t`; and there may be multiple code points per *c-char*, i.e. the number of elements in the array might be more than the number of characters that seem to appear in the string.

---

To answer the question in the title: I'm not aware of any compiler option (for any compiler) that would let you configure the endianness of `char16_t`. I would expect any target system to use the same endianness for all the integral types. `char16_t` is supposed to have the same properties as `uint_least16_t` ([basic.fundamental]/5).

If your code contains string literals and you want to write them into a file as specifically UTF16-BE for example, you'll need to do the usual endian checks/adjustments in case your system stores `char16_t` in little endian form.